Wire conditionally instantiated with generate is not visible later
I'm seeing failing errors both from iverilog and verilator in a module which has a wire instantiated based on a condition. This was originally happening in a SystemVerilog module I got from someone else who had apparently successfully simulated and synthesized the code with Xilinx tools. I've created a much simpler Verilog example that exhibits the same problem.
The code:
module test_gen
    #(parameter OPERATION_TYPE = 0)
    (
        input  logic [31:0] a,
        input  logic [31:0] b,
        output logic [63:0] z
    );
    generate 
        if (OPERATION_TYPE == 0) begin
        wire foo;
        end
    endgenerate
    wire [63:0] zz;

    generate
        always @ (a,b) begin
        if (OPERATION_TYPE == 0) begin
            assign foo = a[0] & b[0];
            z <= {foo, 63'b0};
        end
        else if (OPERATION_TYPE == 1) begin
            z <= a - b;
        end
        else if (OPERATION_TYPE == 2) begin
            z <= (a << 1) + b; // 2a+b
        end
        else begin
            z <= b - a;
        end
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule

iverilog fails with the message:

test_gen.v:18: error: Could not find
variable foo'' in test_gen'' test_gen.v:19: error: Unable to bind
wire/reg/memory foo' in test_gen'
(it will compile if OPERATION_TYPE is set to a non-zero value)

verilator 4.211 issues an error as well:

%Error: test_gen.v:18:20: Can't find definition of variable: 'foo'
18 |             assign foo = a[0] & b[0];
|                    ^~~ %Error: Exiting due to 1 error(s)

So it's as if the wire foo was never instantiated even though the condition was true.
Is conditionally instantiating a wire like this legal Verilog/SystemVerilog? Or is it not legal and the Xilinx tools are just more lenient?

@toolic - This is a standalone module compiled with: $ verilator --lint-only  -Wall test_gen.v

This could never have worked as you cannot make a procedural assignment to a wire foo.

You cannot access identifiers declared in an unnamed begin/end block from outside that block. You must give it a name. Also, the if statements in the second generate are procedural statements, not generate-if constructs. Generate constructs are at the top-level of a module declaration, they cannot be put inside an always block. I think this is what was intended.
module test_gen
    #(parameter OPERATION_TYPE = 0)
    (
        input  logic [31:0] a,
        input  logic [31:0] b,
        output logic [63:0] z
    );
    generate 
      if (OPERATION_TYPE == 0) begin : myname
        wire foo;
        end
    endgenerate

    generate
        if (OPERATION_TYPE == 0) begin
          assign myname.foo = a[0] & b[0];
          assign z = {myname.foo, 63'b0};
        end
        else if (OPERATION_TYPE == 1) begin
            assign z = a - b;
        end
        else if (OPERATION_TYPE == 2) begin
            assign z = (a << 1) + b; // 2a+b
        end
        else begin
            assign z = b - a;
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule

BTW, generate/endgenerate keywords are optional in Verilog. The compiler can determine when the if/case/for constructs are generated or procedural based on what level they appear in the code.

iverilog gives me the following error with that code: test_gen2.v:17: error: reg z; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.

EDIT: I see what's wrong: the 'logic' in the input and output declarations is really a SystemVerilog construct (which I forgot to remove when trying to come up with a simpler testcase and to make it so I could compile with a verilog compiler (iverilog))

The code has compile errors on every simulator on EDA Playground.

This was originally happening in a SystemVerilog module I got from
someone else who had apparently successfully simulated and synthesized
the code with Xilinx tools.

Perhaps the code you got was not really working as you think.  Or perhaps the Xilinx tools are more lenient.  Regardless, the code you posted has problems and can not be used as-is with other tools.
As simple workaround is to always declare the wire (not inside the generate).
